# Create .BAT file to rename files in current directory with input

Tags: batch-file, command

I am trying to write a small .bat script (with limited programming knowledge) that will allow users to enter a value for current version number (e.g. 01) and new version number (e.g. 02) and then use those two numbers inside a rename command.

```
echo off
cls
TITLE Version Updater
echo Use this script to update file names. This works similar to find and replace in other programs.
echo[
echo Enter the current version number (01 for example)
echo off
set /p current="Current Version: "
echo[
echo Enter the new version number (01 becomes 02 etc.)
echo off
set /p new="New Version: "
echo[
echo You will be updating all occurences of "%current%" in your file names to "%new%", if this is correct then continue, if not close this window.
pause
cd %CD%
rename *%current%* *%new%*
pause
```

I think the code is almost right, I am just having troubles with making it reference the current directory that it is run from. I am using this script with people who have limited computer skills, and I am not the network administrator so I cannot really do anything too in depth.

If someone could please help me tweak this then that would be great.

Cheers,

Mat

Edit 1 - Comment response
For example, test_01.tab changing to test_02.tab. It basically will replace all _01 parts of the file name and change them to _02. In this case, current = 01 and new = 02. The filenames are all different though, so you may have test_01.bat, testing_01.bat to change, so just renaming the 01 to 02 is how I assumed it would work.

Edit 2 - Current code
This is thanks to Stephan below, I believe the only thing it needs to be working correct is for the file path to be removed from the second part of the REN command so that it just has the file and extension and it should work.

```
@pushd %~dp0
@Echo off
CLS
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set /p current="Current Version: "
set /p new="New Version: "

for /R %%a in (*_%current%*) do (
  set "Name=%%~a"
  ren "%%~a" "!Name:_%current%=_%new%!"
)
pause
```

Edit 3 - Final Code (works, yay!)

```
@pushd %~dp0
@echo off
cls
TITLE CEF File Version Updater
echo This script will update CEF file versions for TLS rejections (E.G. 4XXX_XX_1 to 4XXX_XX_2). Backup files prior to running this script as a safety measure.
echo[
echo Enter the current version number (no underscore)
echo off
set /p current="Current Version: "
echo[
echo Enter the new version number (no underscore)
echo off
set /p new="New Version: "
echo[
echo You will be updating all occurences of "_%current%" in your file names to "_%new%", is this correct?

SET /P ANSWER=Do you want to continue (Y/N)? 
if /i {%ANSWER%}=={y} (goto :yes) 
if /i {%ANSWER%}=={yes} (goto :yes) 
goto :no 
:yes 

rename *_%current%.* *_%new%.*
CLS
echo Renaming is complete, please check the new file names are correct.
pause 
exit /b 0 

:no  
exit /b 1
```

Comment: Can you give any examples of what its supposed to do? For example whats the filenames that its supposed to rename?  What %current% and %new% could be...?

Comment: For example, test_01.tab changing to test_02.tab. It basically will replace all _01 parts of the file name and change them to _02. In this case, current = 01 and new = 02. The filenames are all different though, so you may have test_01.bat, testing_01.bat to change, so just renaming the 01 to 02 is how I assumed it would work.

Comment: Please put this additional information in the question by editing your post!

Comment: Did a bunch of testing and figured a solution out for you. Posting it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@Echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set /p current="Current Version: "
set /p new="New Version: "

for /R %%a in (*_%current%.*) do (
  set "Name=%%~nxa"
  ECHO ren "%%~a" "!Name:_%current%=_%new%!"
)
pause
```

(remove `ECHO`, if the output satisfies you)

Comment: To echo what I said below, I tried this one and it produced interesting results. The first 3 ren's that appear are for random files in Users\Business\AppData\Roaming\and so on... but the 4th was on the Test folder on the desktop where I have this. I just dragged the script into the cmd, I wonder if it is getting confused on it's location somehow

Comment: just add a `cd /d "c:\my test folder"`.

Comment: Is there a way that I don't have to make that a hard coded thing? This script will be used in a lot of different locations. I was kind of hoping it could just be run and then work

Comment: how should it know, which Location to process? The Folder, where the script is stored? the current working Directory of your `cmd` window? Something else?

Comment: Sorry to blanket reply, but I just rank it again and it seems to be working with the file location, it seems to be an error on my behalf for that. I removed the echo and it says "The syntax of the command is incorrect.". An example of the echo'd ren is "ren "C:\Users\Business\Desktop\Test\Test_01.txt" "C:\Users\Business\Desktop\Test\Test_02.txt"... it seems like this is correct syntax to me so I am unsure

Comment: No Syntax Errors here. Are there files with an exlamation mark (`!`)? That might ruin the syntax

Comment: Hi Stephan, I have tried it at work and I think I know the issue. I believe the file path is only needed once, so it should be "ren "C:\Users\Business\Desktop\Test\Test_01.txt" "Test_02.txt". Are you able to assist me to modify this as I am fairly certain this is the issue.

Comment: That's easy with `~nx` modifier. See my edit. For Explanation see `for /?`

Comment: I will amend my main topic with the final code I ended up with. It is doing the job perfectly now. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick.

```
@Echo off
set /p current="Current Version: "
set /p new="New Version: "

for /R "c:\your location" %%a in (*_%current%.*) do (
ren *_%current%.* *_%new%.*
)
pause
```

Below is before and after running the script on a couple of test-files.

[image] [image]

Comment: Hey Mads, I tried this code and I got the following return.

Current Version: 01, 
New Version: 02, 
The system cannot find the file specified. 
The system cannot find the file specified. 
The system cannot find the file specified. 
Press any key to continue...

Comment: Thats weird. I'm running the script on my computer as we speak and it works like a charm. If you copy-paste my exact script and try again, will it give you the same result? Could be an idea to run the script as admin or perhaps add `setlocal enabledelayedexpansion` below Echo off in the script...?

Comment: Hrm, so before I have been dragging the .bat file into a cmd window and going for that and no dice, I tried just running it as admin from the folder and it just asked for the version and then did nothing. An idea I think may be worth looking at is when I tried another comment by Stephan above, the echo output it gave for the directory was Users\Business\AppData\Roaming\TS3Client\logs\ts3client_20etc.log.... Is there an issue with dragging the .bat into cmd potentially?

Comment: You could also try to add your location to the script like this: `for /R "c:\your location" %%a in` and then the rest as in my answer. I updated my answer. Note that the script has to either 1) be in the folder you want to edit files or 2) you have to specify where the script shall run within the script.